# Elasticsearch indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

In current project I work on I want to improve  search functionality. After reading some stuff in internet , I  decided to go for Elasticsearch. So I have few questions.
I already have production database populated with data. What is the best way to index that database?
And when I want to add new record to database do I will need to added it elastic search ? or maybe create some kind of job to index data one a while?
How do we keep data consistence in 2 databases(production db, Elasticsearch db) ?

Any suggestions, links, comments etc. are very welcome 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still require an answer but I currently use Logstash. I basically have a jdbc sql plugin for input and the elasticsearch plugin for output. You basically configure a config file setting up connections, executing the query and then data mutation and output.

If you take a look at the documentation at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html

An example of the config can be seen below and I've read you can schedule this to transfer data from an sql database to the index, although I have not set this up personally.

Please keep in mind that you would need to secure this data transfer, the sql plugin does offer support for this.

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "file directory to sql driver"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => ""
jdbc_user => ""
jdbc_password => ""
lowercase_column_names => false
statement => "SELECT IGF_UID AS id, IGF_NAME AS name FROM dbo.IGT_ENTITY" 
}
 }
filter {
if ![id] {
    mutate {
                replace =>  {"id" => "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
            }
  }

  }
mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@timestamp" ]
    remove_field => [ "@version" ]
  }

 }

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "entities"
    document_type => "entity"
    manage_template => false
    }
}
```